# using a list inside a function

Tags: list, function

Here is my code for a "check roulette" game that decides who in the party will pay the bill at a restaurant

```
names_string = input("Give me everybody's names, separated by a comma. ")

names = names_string.split(", ")



number = len(names)

roulette_number = random.randint(0,number - 1)

print((names[roulette_number]),"is going to buy the meal today!")
```

my question is, why did i have to add the -1 in the randint function to select the roulette number? why wouldn't it just be `roulette_number = random.randint(0,number)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did -1 because number is the length of the list names suppose you names are

```
["Sam", "Jack"]
```

then the number variable will store 2, but the available index are only 0 and 1, this is beacuse list follow 0-based indexing.

So by doing -1 we ensure that our random integer is always in the list index range.

Comment: Thank you so much! i ended up getting the correct solution but i wanted to understand why.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `random.randint(a, b)` returns a random integer `N` such that `a <= N <= b`. See the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint).

To see why this is a problem, assume (as in Harsh's example) that you have two names: `names = ["Sam", "Jack"]`.

You'll call `random.randint(0, 2)`, which will return one of `0`, `1`, or `2`. *But* there are only two names in your array, with indexes `0` and `1`. If `roulette_number` is `2`, you'll get an exception when accessing the non-existent array member.

You have several options:

- If you're using Python 3.x, you can use `random.randrange()` instead, which excludes the final value from the results. See the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange). That is: `random.randrange(0, 2)` will return `0` or `1`.
- You can (as you did) subtract one from the count, giving you (in the 2-item example) `random.randint(0, 1)`, which will return `0` or `1`.
- (Generally, don't do this one) You can call `random.randint(1, count)`, which will (in the same 2-item example) return `1` or `2`. Then you subtract the result from the array indexer: `names[roulette - 1]`, giving you index `0` or index `1`. I mention this option for completeness. It's not idiomatic (Python devs are used to zero-based thinking), and you'll likely confuse anyone reading your code.